# Getting build failed while trying build Apache Fineract into locally using intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, build, cucumber, apache-fineract

> Task :fineract-provider:cucumber FAILED

> Task :fineract-provider:checkstyleMain
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] C:\Users\Fineract4\fineract\fineract-provider\src\main\java\org\apache\fineract\infrastructure\gcm\domain\Message.java:1: File has Windows (CR+LF) instead of UNIX (LF) end of line (EOL) delimiters. [RegexpMultiline]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] C:\Users\Fineract4\fineract\fineract-provider\src\main\java\org\apache\fineract\infrastructure\gcm\domain\Notification.java:1: File has Win
> Task :fineract-provider:checkstyleMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':fineract-provider:cucumber'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: The execution failed

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> #######################################################################
> Task :fineract-provider:testClasses
> Skipping task ':fineract-provider:testClasses' as it has no actions.
> Resolve mutations for :fineract-provider:cucumber (Thread[Execution worker Thread 5,5,main]) started.
> :fineract-provider:cucumber (Thread[Execution worker Thread 6,5,main]) started.
> Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program

> Task :fineract-provider:cucumber FAILED
> Caching disabled for task ':fineract-provider:cucumber' because:
> Caching has not been enabled for the task
> Task ':fineract-provider:cucumber' is not up-to-date because:
> Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
> Excluding []

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':fineract-provider:checkstyleMain'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleAction
> Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/Fineract4/fineract/fineract-provider/build/reports/checkstyle/main.html
> Checkstyle files with violations: 2
> Checkstyle violations by severity: [error:2]
> ##############################################################################
> Task :fineract-provider:checkstyleMain
> Excluding [commons-codec:commons-codec, com.google.collections:google-collections]
> Build cache key for task ':fineract-provider:checkstyleMain' is d5a1f5053c8e1d4b8d946249282a313b
> Task ':fineract-provider:checkstyleMain' is not up-to-date because:
> Task has failed previously.
> Starting process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 4'. Working directory: C:\Users.gradle\workers Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe -Dcheckstyle.enableExternalDtdLoad=false --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED @C:\Users.gradle.tmp\gradle-worker-classpath2392578964606199869txt -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Worker Daemon 4'
> Successfully started process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 4'
> Started Gradle worker daemon (0.481 secs) with fork options DaemonForkOptions{executable=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe, minHeapSize=null, maxHeapSize=null, jvmArgs=[--add-opens, java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED], keepAliveMode=SESSION}.
> Running checkstyle with toolchain 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17'.
> [ant:checkstyle] Running Checkstyle 10.12.7 on 3178 files
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] C:\Users\Fineract4\fineract\fineract-provider\src\main\java\org\apache\fineract\infrastructure\gcm\domain\Message.java:1: File has Windows (CR+LF) instead of UNIX (LF) end of line (EOL) delimiters. [RegexpMultiline]
> [ant:xslt] Processing C:\Users\Fineract4\fineract\fineract-provider\build\reports\checkstyle\main.xml to C:\Users\Fineract4\fineract\fineract-provider\build\reports\checkstyle\main.html
> [ant:xslt] Loading stylesheet

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="gradleVersion"/>

```
<xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />

<xsl:template match="checkstyle">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Checkstyle Violations</title>
            <!-- vaguely adapted from Gradle's CSS -->
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    color: #02303A;
                }

                a {
                    color: #1DA2BD;
                }
                a.link {
                    color: #02303A;
                }

                p {
                    font-size: 1rem;
                }

                h1 a[name] {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background: white;
                }

                th {
                    font-weight:bold;
                }
                tr {
                    background: #efefef;
                }
                table th, td, tr {
                    font-size:100%;
                    border: none;
                    text-align: left;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <a name="top"><h1>Checkstyle Results</h1></a>
            </p>
            <hr align="left" width="95%" size="1"/>
            <h2>Summary</h2>
            <table class="summary" width="95%" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Total files checked</th>
                    <th>Total violations</th>
                    <th>Files with violations</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:number level="any" value="count(descendant::file)"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:number level="any" value="count(descendant::error)"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:number level="any" value="count(descendant::file[error])"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr align="left" width="95%" size="1"/>
            <div class="violations">
                <h2>Violations</h2>
                <p>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="count(descendant::error) > 0">
                            <table class="filelist" width="95%">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>File</th>
                                    <th>Total violations</th>
                                </tr>
                                <xsl:for-each select="file[error]">
                                    <!-- sort by number of errors and then alphabetically -->
                                    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="count(descendant::error)"/>
                                    <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
                                    <xsl:variable name="errors" select="count(descendant::error)"/>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="#{generate-id(@name)}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></td>
                                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$errors"/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </table>
                            <p/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates>
                                <!-- sort entries by file name alphabetically -->
                                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                            <p/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            No violations were found.
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr align="left" width="95%" size="1"/>
            <p>Generated by <a href="https://gradle.org"><xsl:value-of select="$gradleVersion"/></a> with <a href="https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/">Checkstyle <xsl:value-of select="@version"/></a>.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- A single file with violations -->
<xsl:template match="file[error]">
    <div class="file-violation">
        <h3>
            <a class="link" name="{generate-id(@name)}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a>
        </h3>
        <table class="violationlist" width="95%">
            <tr>
                <th>Severity</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Line Number</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="error"/>
        </table>
        <p/>
        <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
        <p/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- A single row in the list of violations -->
<xsl:template match="error">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@severity"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@message"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@line"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

> Task :fineract-provider:checkstyleMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':fineract-provider:checkstyleMain'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleAction
> Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/Fineract4/fineract/fineract-provider/build/reports/checkstyle/main.html
> Checkstyle files with violations: 2
> Checkstyle violations by severity: [error:2]

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

I have tried to clone every branch separately also did multiple times build and run but no luck.
I want to build and run the Apache Fineract projet in my local machine successfully without any error.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you run the build from OS Command Prompt? How do you trigger the build from IDEA? From the its' Terminal or via Gradle Tool Window?